# Make JQuery AJAX Run returned Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a link, which I want to make a DELETE request with JQuery with AJAX.

```
if(confirm("Are you sure?")) {
   $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr("href"),
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
            // Do something with the result
        }
    });
}
```

`result` is a wad of Javascript I would like to run. How do I get it to run my returned script?

Comment: Please don't do that. Don't return Javascript code, don't `eval`, just return some kind of identifier and let your Javascript decide what to do.

Comment: @bazmegakapa Are you saying this for a separation of concerns purpose or is there a technical reason why this is a bad idea?

Comment: `eval` should be avoided whenever possible. I don't think there is a real reason for returning a piece of code. You could return some kind of JSON, and define in your Javascript what should happen to it.

Comment: Mainly security reasons. a Hacker may be able to inject malicious code into your site.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
success: function(result) {
    eval(result);
}
```

Comment: Don't feel dumb - it's easy to forget built in functions if you don't use them often.

Comment: Are there any risks attached to using eval() in this use case?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `dataType: 'script'` option

```
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr("href"),
    type: 'DELETE',
    dataType: 'script'
});
```

Or simply,

```
$.getScript($(this).attr("href")); // Won't use 'DELETE' http type
```

Comment: Nice. This fits better with the rest of my Javascript. :)

Answer (score 2):

Check the javascript [Eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) method. It allows you to execute js code which is represented as a string.